# 400 Bad Request while publishing the Entity Framework WCF Services in another system?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

In local machine the services are running fine.But i need to place that services in client system.
I changed the connection string properly and permissions all are correct.But i am getting 400 bad request error when the files was published into that server system.in entity framework any files need to place while publishing.I am new to write the EF wcf services.
Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 bad request is a http error message.

Since you get this error when you deploy to a new system, it is probably related to the IIS configuration on the new server. For example you could get this error if ASP.Net was not enabled on the new server.